# Understanding SpeedFan terminology

Tags: graphics-card, temperature, nvidia-geforce, speedfan

There has been a [lot](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=193106) [of](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=214329) [people](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=213926) [posting](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=214260) problems running Battlefield 3 with an Nvidia card, specficially the [GTX 560Ti](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-us.html).

Something doesn't sound right - if it really was a driver problem, then I would expect a great variety of issues with a broader range of cards.

So I ran [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) just to see what was going on:
[image: Speed Fan]

I jumped in and out of the game a few times and you can clear see when - as soon as I quit the game the heat drops off very quickly.

So my question is:

1. What / where is Temp1, Temp2 and Temp3 on the card?
2. And what range should I be aiming for?
3. How hot must the card get before Nvidia will crash to desktop?
4. Does Nvidia write to a log file (or similar) to tell you why it has crashed to desktop?

+70 degrees sounds awfully high. Speedfan suggests that anything over 50 degrees is too hot.

**Update**

Sorry, just to clarify, if I run Battlefield 3 at full screen, high settings I get about 4 - 5 minutes of play and then the game crashes.  I get maybe 12 - 15 minutes if I run the game at 640 x 420 windowed.  Graphics card is [GTX 560Ti](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-us.html), OS: Win 7 64bit.  Same problem running Nvidia drivers version 285.38 & 285.62

Comment: The core slowdown threshold in my Ubuntu 125C (8500GT).  http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=133010

Comment: 70 is reasonable for a GPU under load. Trip temperature on GPUs is somewhere around 110-125.

Comment: Do YOU have an actual problem running Battlefield 3? Can't see a specific problem being described, just a reference to another forum.